# INSERT INTO mySQL procedure

Tags: mysql, insert, procedure

INSERT INTO in MySQL>

this is a part of code a procedure:

```
if ParentList is null then

        set @sql=concat('insert into ', table_name, tabSave, '(md5Id, CommentsId, Parent, Content, UserId, Title, Nick) ',
        'values(', @md5Id, ', ', CommentsId, ', null, \'', Content, '\'' ,UserId,',',Title,',',Nick, ')');
else
    set @sql=concat('insert into ', table_name, tabSave, '(md5Id, CommentsId, Parent, Content, UserId, Title, Nick) ',
        'values(', @md5Id, ', ', CommentsId, ', ', @Parent, ', \'', Content, '\ ,', UserId,', ', Title,', ', Nick, ')');
end if;
```

This character sign ' is badly inserted and I dont know where :

My error:

```
CALL AddDynamicTable3('asd65xb', 'xxx', 5, NULL, 'MojWstep', 22, 'New title', 'Ethan')  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '22,New title,Przemo)' at line 1
```

XXX - table_name

other variables are not significant example tabSave, table_name ...

Earlier I wrote the same procedure but without three variables UserId, Title, Nick and its OK but when I put this variables I only see ERROR.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
'\ ,', UserId,',
```

from the second query, change to

```
'\ ', UserId,',
```

Comment: its the second line from the bottom

Comment: now you have a different problem, its in the element previous to the one you just fixed.

Comment: 0 14:55:53 CALL AddDynamicTable3('asd65xb', 'xxx', 5, NULL, 'MojWstep', 22, 'New title', 'Ethan') Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''MojWstep,22,New title,Ethan)' at line 1